# What are all these *.cm[a-z] files and when we need them

Tags: ocaml

OCaml have various extensions for compiled files: `*.a`, `*.cma`, `*.cmi`, `*.cmx`, `*.cmxa`, `*.cmxs` (and, perhaps, this is not exhaustive list). What are they and in which cases do I need them?

If I have a library, which files do I need to ship with it. I noticed some people blindly install all *.cm[a-z] files into the archive, but is it really required?

Comment: I guess you may read this a bit:https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/the-compiler-backend-byte-code-and-native-code.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I suggest you read the overview section of the [byte code](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/comp.html#sec242) and [native code](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/native.html#sec259) compilers as this will greatly improve you understanding of what these files are.

Now more specifically if your library is a set of modules caracterized by a set of `.mli`/`.ml` files:

- A `cmi` file hold the compiled interfaces of your module (result of compiling a `.mli` file). For each module of your library that you want other people to be able to use you need to install them (i.e. the `cmi` define your public interface). It's also a good practice to install the `mli` files so that people can have a peek at them. These days you should also install the `cmti` files (generated using `-bin-annot` option) which are annotated compiled interfaces and that can be used by tools like `ocp-index`, `odoc` and `odig`.
- `cma` files hold an archive of the result of byte code comipilation (`cmo` files) of your library. You should install them if you want people to be able to compile with your library to byte code.
- `cmxa` and `.a` files hold an archive of the result of native code compilation (`cmx`/`o` files) of your library. They are the pendent of `cma` files but for native code. You need to install them if you want people to be able to compile with your library to native code.
- `cmxs` are the pendant of `cmxa` for native dynlinking. You need to install them if you want users of your library to be able to dynamically load your library in their programs as a plugin using the `Dynlink` module.
- `cmx` files are in the `cmxa` however there is one reason why you may want to also install them. If they can be seen at seperate compilation time along with the `cmi` files they allow the compiler to perform cross-module inlining. The files separately compiled that way do however become dependent on that implementation which means that they will need a recompile if the `cmx` changes (i.e. the implementation) even if the `cmi` (i.e. the interface) did not.

Note that in general it's good if you are able to compile and install *all* of these files <strike>(though sometimes for some reasons you may want to not install the `cmx` files so that you can separately compile against a `cmi` and be able to switch implementation without a recompile)</strike> (see the `-opaque` compilation flag if you need this).

On final thing to note is that in OCaml there is no proper name spacing: every toplevel module is defined in a global namespace. This means that you need to be very careful in the toplevel module names you put in library, **even if you don't export their cmi**. Especially avoid generic terms that could be used by other libraries, use a short prefix for your library e.g. `MyLib_file` rather `File` (and again even if `File` turns out to be an internal module that you have in the `cma` but whose `cmi` you don't export it could clash with other private or public `File` modules defined in other libraries)

Comment: What is `cmxas` (I've never seen this extension)?  Also, you neglected to mention `.cmxs`.  Is `cmxas` a typo for `cmxs`?

Answer (score 1):

https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/the-compiler-backend-byte-code-and-native-code.html is a good resource you can read for your question.

for a summary:

[image]

Comment: Link is currently dead (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE), but http://web.archive.org/web/20191211191353/https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/the-compiler-backend-byte-code-and-native-code.html works